# How to kill programs in the same directory in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kill

I want to kill all programs running in the same directory as I do.
I need to find which programs are running right now and kill them (and to be careful to not kill myself).
I am running my program in Ubuntu(Linux).

I need to use this command:

```
int kill(pid_t pid, int sig);
```

How I can do it?

*The programs live in the same directory .

Comment: Your question is ambiguous with regard to programs running in the "same directory". Are you talking about processes that have binaries that live in the same direcory, or processes that were started with the same working directory?

Comment: Have a look at `lsof` and good luck.

Comment: BTW, it's incorrect to refer to that as a "command"; it's a system function. There is `kill` command, but that's different.

Comment: Do you understand what arguments `kill()` takes? [The first arg is the PID](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill), which you'll need to obtain.

Comment: thanks! I knows the kill system call and it arguments

Answer (score 2):

Stricto sensu, your question does not make sense. By the time you are getting the directory of a process, it could have called [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) before you kill it (and then you should not have killed it).

On Linux, to get information about processes, use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). So use [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) after [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) on `/proc/` (filter only the numerical directories, like `/proc/1234/` which corresponds to process of pid 1234). For each process there, use [readlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html) on  `/proc/1234/cwd` to get its directory (and on `/proc/1234/exe` to get its executable, if it matters). Use [getcwd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcwd.2.html) and [getpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html) to get current directory and current process.

BTW, your [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) is a [syscall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)), not a command. The command is [kill(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) to be usually run from a shell.

You should read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

At last, your desired behavior to kill every process running in your directory is extremely user unfriendly. So at least document it, and perhaps give some way to disable that behavior. A more gentle way would be to make some *temporary directory* (using [mkdtemp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkdtemp.3.html)) then [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) into it (then perhaps [unlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html) or [rmdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rmdir.2.html) it).

See also [pkill(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pkill.1.html) and `pgrep`

Comment: All the programs are running from the the same folder (and I know which one) and I need to "find" what the pid of the processes and to kill them.

Comment: But you should explain why you need to kill them. It looks crazy! BTW Linux has directories, not folders....

Comment: Sorry about my mistakes(I don't know Linux so well..) and its The Last Survivor Contest in C.

Comment: So you can help me to find what the pid of the processes and to kill them?

Comment: I gave all the necessary information in my answer. Read all the linked material.

Comment: I didn't understand how to find the pid of the processes.

Comment: You need to read more carefully all the material I gave you. Did you code something doing `opendir` then `readdir` on `/proc/`? **What did you try?** Add debugging prints to your program, compile it with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`), **use the debugger** (`gdb`). Then perhaps ask another question and *show your source code*

Comment: I cant open a new question. I didn't understand what to do when I get to readdir(what I need to read?) and what to do with proc?